# Invoke ASP.Net Core MVC controller action with parameter doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple ASP.NET Core MVC controller action method defined as:

```cs
public class MyMVCController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(String usrid)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I call it using this URI:

```
https://localhost:6009/MyMVC/MyAction/073214df
```

My action gets invoked and I get return back, but the parameter `usrid` is always null. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

@Jackdaw's first solution, change parameter name from `usrid` to `id` worked for me. However, the ones with attributes don't. While the parameter does get passed in, the action will fail because the `accessToken` somehow returns null in the line below. This is not the case in the first solution.

```cs
[Route("MyMVC/MyAction/{usrid?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(String usrid)
{
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        // ...
}
```

Finally, I figured out how to get the attribute based routing solutions to work - adding another attribute `[Authorize]` to the action method. Don't ask me why I have to do this and why I don't in the `usrid`/`id` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s because the default route pattern has the following definition:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Therefore, if change the method parameter name to `id` it will work:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(String id)
```

Or you can apply the following route attribute to the method:

```cs
[Route("MyMVC/MyAction/{usrid?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(String usrid)
{
    // ...
}
```

Test screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Comment: @Alexu: You are welcome! Additional option: you can apply `[Route("{controller}/{action}")]` attribute to the controller `MyMVCController` class and apply `[Route("{usrid?}")]` to the `public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(String usrid)` method. It should work too.

Comment: Thanks again @Jackdaw! But for whatever reason, the only way works for me is by change the name usrid to id. For both of those two options with attributes, I will get the correct parameter passed in, but the action will fail on authentication. See my update above.

Comment: @Alexu: Very strange, because it's working for me. See the attached screenshot.

Comment: yes, it is strange. Can't imagine this routing thing has anything to do with access token... and if I bypass authentication, it will work perfectly! Well, at least I have one solution now, thanks to your help :).

Comment: @Alexu: See the following article [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241702/discussion-between-jackdaw-and-alexu).